# how can we compute this result?

Tags: combinatorics

Five digit number divisible by 3 is formed using 0,1,2,3,4,6 and 7 without repetition. Total number of such numbers are.
How can we compute the answer in the shortest possible time, i mean without forming the numbers which sum upto a divisible of 3?

Answer (score 3):

use the fact that a number is divisible by $3$ if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by $3$

Comment: I asked how can we find the answer in shortest possible time, that is without finding the possible combinations. But still thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Find number of the combinations so that sum of digit of 5 digits is divisible by 3(eg. 7,4,1,3,6 is one) split those combinations into those that don't have zero as one of the digits let's call them $a_1$ and the one's with the zero $a_0$.The solution is $a_1*5!+a_0*4*4*3*2*1$

Comment: Of the seven digits, two are unused, and there are $\tbinom72=21$ ways to choose them. Because $0+1+2+3+4+6+7=23$, the sum of the two omitted digits must be congruent to $2\pmod3$. This can either be $0+2$ or $1+1$, and the choices are therefore limited to $\{(0,2),(3,2),(6,2),(1,4),(1,7),(4,7)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

For 0, 3 and 6, we assign the value 0

For 1, 4 and 7, we assign the value 1

For 2 and 5 we assign the value -1.

Any number divisible by three has the property that the sum of its digits is also divisible by 3. I.e, if their total, newly assigned, sum is -3, 0 or 3.

E.g.

26436 gives -1 + 0 + 1 + 3 + 0 = 3, so it is divisible by 3.

Now, try and find a way of gathering these:
We can have all '0's, and for all '1's we need either 2 more '1's or a '-1'...
This continues in an obvious manner, until you've found all possible combinations, without checking all the sums:)